# How to cite an ancient manuscript, translated, in a volume of an edited collection (CMOS)?

Tags: citations, chicago-manual-of-style, footnotes

I've run into a particular complication that I cannot find a detailed explanation for.

In general terms, I'm writing a paper in which I reference an ancient manuscript, but I'm using a translation of that manuscript. That translation is located in one volume of a 14-volume collection. That volume has a title, as well as a volume number. The collection is the second of a series. The series was edited by two people, neither of whom is the translator.

For the sake of other users, I'd like to know the algorithm for putting these things together so that we can solve other complicated citations as well. Maybe this algorithm is deep in the bowels of the Chicago Manual of Style, and I'm just not looking in the right place. Maybe, citations should never get this complicated, and I'm not thinking the right way about how citation works.

In more specific terms, this is St Jerome's Letter 22 called "To Eustochium" translated into English by William Henry Fremantle found on pp 22-41 in Vol 6 of 14 of "A Select Library of Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers of the Christian Church: Second Series" edited by Philip Schaff and Henry Wace. I'd like to cite this source based on the CMOS.

So, the CMOS bibliography entry I have looks like this (tabs/indenting ignored):

> Jerome. “To Eustochium.” Translated by William Henry Fremantle in *Volume VI. St. Jerome: Letters and select works*, edited by Philip Schaff and Henry Wace, 22-41. Vol. 6 of *A Select Library of Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers of the Christian Church: Second Series*. New York, United States: The Christian Literature Company, 1912.

So... I have two questions.
Firstly, is the above citation correct?
Secondly, what would the (full) footnote for this bibliography entry look like?
I'm pretty sure a reasonable shortened note would be

> Jerome, "To Eustochium."

Comment: CMOS 14.242-14.252 deals with classical references, I think that would apply here. Another idea might be to look at papers/articles/books that cite similar works and see how they do it.

Comment: Usually "mechanical" style issues such as this will depend on where you want to publish. (Or submit to if it is a document for university credit of some kind, such as PhD thesis, class esssay, etc.) Look for examples of similar things that have been published in the same place. Look for official advice from editors or professors etc.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you need to find the way that scholars refer to the letter. This would letter 22. I am not sure which line of the letter. If you are not writing for  Patristic scholars, you can use the Loeb Classics Library, and find the reference there.

In this case (for example only -- I don't know what section your selection is) the 25th section of the letter is Jerome, Letters, 22.25 (LCL 262: 110-111). That is, it is in Loeb Classics Library volume 262, pages 110-111. If you are writing for Patristics scholars simply Jerome, Letters, 22.25 is enough, I think. If you want to help everyone, put both the original Latin and your English translation in. If you use another translator, put that in, but make sure you put in the ones that patristics scholars can easily find without an old edition of the writer.

But the best thing is to find the target journal and find a reference, which you can do on the journal website as they usually allow searching without a subscription. Generally, most journals use the The SBL Handbook of Style, the Society for Biblical Literature handbook. Loeb volumes and SBL handbooks will be at any good library and are available digitally.